# Method of generating a string with results from a curve_fit

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a class which takes a distribution, and fits it.  The method has the option for choosing between a few predefined functions.

As part of printing the class, I print the result of the fit in the form of an equation, where the fit-results and subsequent errors are displayed on the over the figure.

My question is is there a tidy way to handle when a number is negative, such that the string for printing is formed as: "y = mx - c", and not "y = mx + -c".

I developed this with a linear fit, where I simply assess the sign of the constant, and form the string in one of two ways:

```py
def fit_result_string(self, results, errors):
    if self.fit_model is utl.linear:
       if results[1] > 0:
           fit_str = r"y = {:.3}($\pm${:.3})x + {:.3}($\pm${:.3})".format(
               results[0], 
               errors[0], 
               results[1], 
               errors[1])
       else:
           fit_str = r"y = {:.3}($\pm${:.3})x - {:.3}($\pm${:.3})".format(
               results[0], 
               errors[0], 
               abs(results[1]), 
               errors[1]) 
    
    return fit_str
```

I now want to build this up to also be able to form a string containing the results if the fit model is changed to a 2nd, 3rd, or 4th degree polynomial, while handling the sign of each coefficient.

Is there a better way to do this than using a whole bunch of if-else statements?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function which returns '+' or '-' according to the given number, and call it inside a f-string.

```py
def plus_minus_string(n):
    return '+' if n >= 0 else '-'

print(f"y = {m}x {plus_minus_string(c)} {abs(c)}")
```

Examples:

```py
>>> m = 2
>>> c = 5
>>> print(f"y = {m}x {plus_minus_string(c)} {abs(c)}")
y = 2x + 5
>>> c = -4
>>> print(f"y = {m}x {plus_minus_string(c)} {abs(c)}")
y = 2x - 4
```

You will need to change it a bit to fit to your code, but it's quite straight-forward I hope.

Comment: A simple and elegant solution.  I knew there would be a better way to do it than my brute force approach.  Thank you!